# Oracle-Making condition optional in Select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select, where-clause

How to make a condition optional?
That is, if a condition of the `where` clause is FALSE, how to ignore the condition in a simplest way?

The expected result of my code is,

```
RR
--
100
200
```

My Code is,

```
WITH DATASET AS ( 
  SELECT 1 A, 10 B, 100 RR FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT NULL A, 10 B, 200 RR FROM DUAL
)
SELECT RR
FROM DATASET
WHERE 
A=2  -- How to make this condition optional(that is, as 2 is not found then,ignoring this condition)
AND 
B=10 
;
```

Comment: Doesn't `OR` instead of `AND` work? Or you must explain better what you want.

Comment: What do you mean by making it "optional"? If we interpret it literally, it should mean that you can simply delete that condition from the `where` clause entirely. Probably not what you really mean though. From the data you provided, perhaps you mean A should be 2 or else A should be `NULL`? Please clarify. Also, please note that the requirements in the `WHERE` clause are called **conditions**, not constraints. This is important, because "constraint" is also a technical word in Oracle, with an entirely different meaning. I will edit your post to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that if not exists 2 in all data you do not want to filter but if there is a 2 in A column then you want to it.

**so try this:**

**SOLUTION 1:**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
WITH DATASET AS ( 
  SELECT 1 A, 10 B, 100 RR FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT NULL A, 10 B, 200 RR FROM DUAL
)
SELECT  
RR
FROM
DATASET
WHERE B=10 
AND EXISTS
(
SELECT 1 FROM DATASET WHERE A=2
)
)
UNION 
SELECT * FROM 
(
WITH DATASET AS ( 
  SELECT 1 A, 10 B, 100 RR FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT NULL A, 10 B, 200 RR FROM DUAL
)
SELECT  
RR
FROM
DATASET
WHERE B=10 
AND NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1 FROM DATASET WHERE A=2
)
)
```

**SOLUTION2 :**

```
WITH DATASET AS ( 
  SELECT 1 A, 10 B, 100 RR FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT NULL A, 10 B, 200 RR FROM DUAL
)
,SUB AS (
SELECT DISTINCT 1 A_EXISTS,RR
FROM DATASET
WHERE A=2
),
SUB2 AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE 
  WHEN SUB.A_EXISTS IS NOT NULL AND DATASET.A=2
    THEN SUB.RR
  WHEN SUB.A_EXISTS IS NOT NULL AND DATASET.A<>2
    THEN NULL
  ELSE DATASET.RR
END RR
FROM
DATASET
FULL OUTER JOIN SUB ON A_EXISTS=1
WHERE  DATASET.B=10  
)
SELECT
*
FROM SUB2
WHERE RR IS NOT NULL
```